# In UI automation, should we validate state changes in the navigation utils itself? Or should we do it in a separate validation util

Tags: validation, selenium, automated-tests, ui-automation, functional-testing

I am using Selenium for our UI automation. We have separate classes for testcases, navigation utilities and validation utilities. In navigation utilities, we write functions that takes us from one page to other, clicking a button, submit a form etc. and in validation utilities we write methods that help us validate the test steps.

I have noticed that we have been writing navigation utilities (methods) without any verification and relying on validation utils for any sort of verification. So, let's say we want to write a submitForm() method. In this method we only perform a click on the sumbit button (which I think is not correct). In my opinion the correct thing would be to do some basic verification in the submitForm() itself (such as validating the response code, validating the URL) and then use the Validation utils for much granular validations.

This adds an extra layer of verification and also this assures the person writing tests that the navigations are working properly.

My question is, is it better to have some validations in navigation utils itself or only navigation should be done in navigation utils and validation of any kind should go in validation utils?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question. Opinion questions are not a good fit for SO. I would recommend you try one of the other sister sites like SQA, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I ensure the navigation is successful (HTTP Status 200 and page finished loading) before continuing. But do not mix this with functional validations/assertions that you will be performing. This way, you can track server errors like 404/500 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your questions one by one:

1. `We have separate classes for testcases, navigation utilities and validation utilities` : This approach looks good enough to perform Automation Testing but ideally an organization should follow one of the following [framework approaches](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/test-automation-frameworks-selenium-tutorial-20/) mentioned below so that moving forward when the number of Testcases, Utilities & Validations are numerous a small change in the Application must be adopted through small changes in your framework. The frameworks are classified as:

`Module Based Testing Framework`

`Library Architecture Testing Framework`

`Data Driven Testing Framework`

`Keyword Driven Testing Framework`

`Hybrid Testing Framework`

`Behavior Driven Development Framework`

Having said that, `PageFactory` using POM (Page Object Modelling) is one of the best Automation Framework interms of performance, maintenance & re-usability.

2. `validating the response code, validating the URL` :  You can always do these Validations through selenium easily through a library even analyzing the response time.
3. `Validation utils for much granular validations` : It much depends on how much granular your organization want to test. Majority of the Web Application page navigation functionality are validated through "Page Title", "Page Icon" or some "Page Headers". Additionally you can get the entire "Page Source" of an Webpage and validate any of the webpage properties.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: I am also a fan of POM for UI automation especially for website automation. That ways it is easier to find out if the module you need is already implemented. We have a lot of duplication in navigation and validation utils just because the automation writer did not know if the method he needed was already there or not and ended up creating a method of his own. Coming back to my question. I think adding a small check in the navigation utils is necessary. You should verify that the method you used ran fine.Eg. When implementing a login module, I'll always see that I was actually logged in or not

Comment: @pkhabya This can happen when an Application evolves but once the Webpages are ready gradually we should move them to PageFactory. Now if this Answer caters to your Question can you please Accept the Answer as a Solution to your Question to close the discussion thread? Please upvote the Answer if it was useful. Thanks